# Как проверить строку на наличие слова?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как проверить строку на наличие слова при помощи регулярных выражений в java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static boolean foo (String line, String reg) {
    String[] strings = line.split(" "); // делим строку на отдельные слова
    for (String word : strings) {

        if (word.matches(reg)) {  // проверяем в цикле каждое отдельное слово
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но меня интересует как это реализовать при помощи регулярных выражений.

Comment: попробуйте такое выражение ".*( word ).*",где word - это искомое слово

Answer (score 5):

Решить задачу можно следующим образом:

```
final String s = "This is a long string! ;)";  // Здесь ищем слово.
final String w = "long";                       // Слово для поиска.
if (s.matches(".*\\b" + w + "\\b.*")) 
    System.out.println("Found! :)");
else 
    System.out.println("Not Found! :(");
```

Для поиска используется метод `String.matches`, который проверяет соответствие строки регулярному выражению.

Следует обратить внимание на использование в регулярном выражении метасимвола `\b`. Он определяет границы слова. Так, например, слово long будет найдено также в строках

```
"long int"
"unsigned long"
```

в то время как `.*( long ).*` "не заметит" искомого слова, стоящего в начале и конце строки. Более того, разделителем слов может быть не только пробел, но и табуляция, точка, запятая и т.п.